# A key cannot be configured on 'ApplicationUser' because it is a derived type, but there is no key configuration on ApplicationUser

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to customize IdentityUser using ApplicationUser, I followed the steps in microsoft article, but when I run the application, I get this error on method `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=A key
>   cannot be configured on 'ApplicationUser' because it is a derived
>   type. The key must be configured on the root type 'IdentityUser'. If
>   you did not intend for 'IdentityUser' to be included in the model,
>   ensure that it is not included in a DbSet property on your context,
>   referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from
>   a navigation property on a type that is included in the model.
>   Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore   StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityType.SetPrimaryKey(IReadOnlyList`1
>   properties, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.PrimaryKey(IReadOnlyList`1
>   properties, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.PrimaryKey(IReadOnlyList`1
>   clrProperties, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasKey(Expression`1
>   keyExpression)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserContext`5.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.b__0(EntityTypeBuilder`1
>   b)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.Entity[TEntity](Action`1
>   buildAction)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserContext`5.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext`8.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Assistente_de_Estagio.Data.ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder) in C:\Users\gui\source\repos\Assistente De
>   Estágio\Assistente de Estagio\Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs:line 40
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder, DbContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder, DbContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext
>   context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator
>   validator)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__1()
>   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)

Context code:

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Curso> Curso { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Documento> Documento { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OpcaoRequisito> OpcaoRequisito { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProgressoDoUsuario> ProgressoDoUsuario { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Requisito> Requisito { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RequisitoDeDocumento> RequisitoDeDocumento { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RequisitoDeUsuario> RequisitoDeUsuario { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

}
```

Comment: Does your `ProgressoDoUsuario` class (or any other class) has a reference on `IdentityUser` ? If so, replace it with `ApplicationUser`

Comment: Hello @Gui. If my answer looks helpful, could you please mark it as correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to replace all places in code where you use IdentityUser to ApplicationUser.

For example in scaffolded Identity/Pages/Account/**Register.cshtml.cs** you need to do these changes:

```
private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
```

To

```
private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
```

I faced the same issue. After I replaced all usage IdentityUser to ApplicationUser in code the Error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in my dbcontext by changing

```
 DbSet<ApplicationUser<string>> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; } to public DbSet<ApplicationUser> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
```