# Migrating EF6 to EF Core setting unable to specify the identity user table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

**Question:**

How do we migrate our EF6 code first application to EF Core and specify an existing table for the identity user?

**Background:**

We are migrating an ASP.NET MVC application that used EF6 to .NET6 and EF Core. The original project was developed with a code first database and used a `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` override for authentication.

**Problem:**

When we need to query the `ApplicationUser` or pull the related data in a query the application throws an error because it is expecting to find the table name `AspNetUsers`, but the table is actually named `ApplicationUsers`. I have been unable to successfully set the table name for the `ApplicationUser`.

**Failed attempts:**

This does nothing

```
[Table( "ApplicationUsers" )]
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
```

This does nothing, as it seems to be overridden by the defaults in the base implementation

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>( b => 
    {
        b.ToTable("ApplicationUsers");
    } );
    ...
    base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );
}
```

This errors on startup with the following error *A key cannot be configured on 'ApplicationUser' because it is a derived type.*

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>( b => 
    {
        b.ToTable("ApplicationUsers");
    } );
    ...
    base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );
}
```

Comment: Option #1, but move your fluent configuration *after* the call to base `OnModelCreating` (last wins).

Comment: check out this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0), if it would be of any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730473/a-key-cannot-be-configured-on-applicationuser-because-it-is-a-derived-type-bu) and be sure to replace all mentions of IdentityUser to ApplicationUser ( so that no one is registering the base IdentityUser as a dbContext set under the hood ) and also run the base model creation before your "extra editions" iinstead of the other way around, by first running

```
base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );
```

and then addiing your own changes on the model buiilder, that will override the previous ones instead

Comment: There weren't any occurrences of IdentiyUser in the code other than in the ApplicationUser so that wasn't an issue, but it was the ordering, which I am sure I had tried previosuly, but either I did and I'd got different errors or not at all, either way, putting the base call first has resolved that issue.