# EF Core 7 in ASP.NET Core : cannot create migration, derived key issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

First off, the error I am getting is this:

> A key cannot be configured on 'FoosballUser' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'AppUser'. If you did not intend for 'AppUser' to be included in the model, ensure that it is not referenced by a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation on a type that is included in the model.

I have two areas: `Foodplan` and `Foosball`.

Each area has it's own `DbContext` and a user class that inherits from a base class.

I should note here that the `Foodplan` area works fine, I have created a migration and updated the database without any issues.

So I clearly have a configuration issue somewhere with the `Foosball` area - I just can't find it.

As for my setup, I have created a base user class that inherits from IdentityUser:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeletedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And the two classes that inherits from this.

```
public class FoodUser : AppUser
{
    // Empty, in case I want to add attributes in the future
}
```

and

```
public class FoosballUser : AppUser
{
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HexCode { get; set; }
    public List<MatchResult>? GameResults { get; set; }
    public int WinStreak { get; set; }
    public int LossStreak { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

And their respective `DbContext` classes:

```
public class FoodContext : IdentityDbContext<FoodUser>
{
    // Dbsets omitted, non related to the user class.

    public FoodContext(DbContextOptions<FoodContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

And the `Foosball` `DbContext`:

```
public class FoosballContext : IdentityDbContext<FoosballUser>
{
    // Dbsets omitted, non related to the user class.

    public FoosballContext(DbContextOptions<FoosballContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

And finally where I register the contexts:

```
// Add the database context
builder.Services.AddDbContext<FoodContext>(dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<FoosballContext>(dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions.UseMySql(foosballConnectionString, serverVersion));

// Add identity
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<FoosballContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultUI();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<FoodContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultUI();
```

Note here, it doesn't matter which order these are in - the `Foodplan` context works fine, the `Foosball` context does not. It also does not matter if I try to create the `Foosball` migration before or after the `Foodplan` migration.

My goal is to have a separate database for logins for each area using the same login setup.

I do not understand the error message as one side of a seemingly identical setup works, while the other does not..

What am I missing here?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730473/a-key-cannot-be-configured-on-applicationuser-because-it-is-a-derived-type-bu

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The culprit was in one of my Foosball models where I was using a `List<AppUser>` instead of `LIst<FoosballUser>`.